# Ant doesn't build second jar

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea

I have an intellij project where I am trying to create 2 jars.  I have setup my buildfile and run build ALL artifacts.  However, only my FIRST jar comes up.  To try to get more information I ran the command line command:  ant -buildfile buildfile.xml

In the result I get the following:

> artifact.jar1:jar:
>
> > [mkdir] Created dir: ~/Projects/proj1/__artifacts_temp/jar1_jar
> >
> > [jar] Building jar: ~/Projects/proj1/__artifacts_temp/jar1.jar
> >
> > [copy] Copying 1 file to ~/Projects/proj1/__artifacts_temp/jar1_jar
>
> artifact.jar2:jar:
>
> > [mkdir] Created dir: ~/Projects/proj1/__artifacts_temp/jar2_jar
> >
> > [jar] Building jar: ~/Projects/proj1/__artifacts_temp/1/jar2.jar
> >
> > [copy] Copying 1 file to ~/Projects/proj1/__artifacts_temp/jar2_jar

So it looks like both jars will be created.  However... the next output is more discouraging.

> build.all.artifacts:
>
> > [copy] Copying 1 file to ~/Projects/proj1
> >
> > [delete] Deleting directory ~/Projects/proj1/__artifacts_temp

I have absolutely no idea why it would only copy 1 of the jars back.  Any thoughts or ideas on how to get more information would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Here is what the build.all.artifacts section of my build script looks like

```
<target name="build.all.artifacts" depends="artifact.jar1:jar, artifact.jar2:jar" description="Build all artifacts">
  <mkdir dir="${artifact.output.jar1:jar}"/>
  <copy todir="${artifact.output.jar1:jar}">
    <fileset dir="${artifact.temp.output.jar1:jar}"/>
  </copy>
  <mkdir dir="${artifact.output.jar2:jar}"/>
  <copy todir="${artifact.output.jar2:jar}">
    <fileset dir="${artifact.temp.output.jar2:jar}"/>
  </copy>

  <!-- Delete temporary files -->
  <delete dir="${artifacts.temp.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check *buildfile.xml*, there should be a <[copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)> task for the first jar and not for the second.

Update: Try using `<fileset dir="${artifact.temp.output.jar2:jar}" erroronmissingdir="true"/>` to see if there's something wrong with the path.
Also try to print the paths to check if they are correct:

```
<echo>${artifact.output.jar2:jar}</echo>
<echo>${artifact.temp.output.jar2:jar}</echo>
```

Comment: I edited my original post to show what that area of my buildscript looks likes.  It seems it should copy for both, correct?

Comment: I'm afraid there was no new output.  Simply said that it only copied one file and deleted the temp directory, followed by BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

Comment: I went a little further and removed the line that deletes the tmp directory.  It looks like in both the jar1/ and jar2/ directories only JAR2 is being created...

Not sure why this is, I must have something incorrect in my buildfile.xml somewhere.  I used intellij to generated it, so it may be possible something went wrong somewhere.

Comment: I believe you were correct originally and that I just led us down the wrong path.  It turns out that the COPY tag under the individual targets were incorrect.

On both copy tags the "tofile" setting was set to the same JAR name.

It is now working correctly.

Thank you for working through this with me